# Use icons in Foundation 6 menus

Tags: icons, zurb-foundation-6

I created a simple F6 app for sites and tried to copy-paste code snippets to display menu with icons. Why id doe not work neither in the topbar menu not in the off-canvas menu section? Here is the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FDashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
      <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="responsive-menu"></button>
      <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
    </div>

    <div class="top-bar" id="responsive-menu">
      <div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
          <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
          <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="#0">One</a>
            <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
              <li><a href="#0">One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#0">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#0">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#0">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Three</span> <i class="fi-list"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="top-bar-right">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="off-canvas-wrapper">
      <button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="offCanvas">Open Menu</button>
      <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>

        <!-- Your menu or Off-canvas content goes here -->

            <!-- Menu -->
        <ul class="vertical menu icons icon-left">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fi-list"></i> <span>One</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fi-list"></i> <span>Two</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fi-list"></i> <span>Three</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fi-list"></i> <span>Four</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content>
        <!-- Your page content lives here -->
        <div class="grid-container">
          <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
            <div class="large-12 cell">
              <h1>Welcome to Foundation</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/what-input/dist/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Adding the below lines to `app.scss` hasn't solved the problem:

```
@include menu-base;
@include menu-expand;
@include menu-align;
@include menu-direction($dir);
@include menu-icon-position;
@include menu-icons;
@include menu-icon-position;
```

What is wrong here ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it to be the best and the right solution. Anyway, it works fine. So if there is a better way, it is always welcome. The described steps were made for a F6 project created with Foundation CLI.

1. Download [Foundation Icon Fonts 3](https://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icon-fonts-3)
2. Unzip the downloaded archive and copy its entire content into `[your-project]/css` folder.
3. Delete `preview.html` file (useless as is used just to display available icons).
4. Reference the icons CSS file in your HTML page as follows `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css" />`. You can put just underneath the generated during project creation `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">` line.
5. Use one of the icons font, for example:
   `<li><a href="#"><span>Three</span> <i class="fi-list"></i></a></li>`

Enjoy :)